# What are your favourite papers about European/American options?

Tags: options, papers

I'm looking for some papers to support some options lessons for non-quant people (mostly traders) and I'd like to know what papers would you recomend that don't have a very strong focus on the mathematical side of it.

Also would definitely be interesting to know what other papers you find interesting regarding this topic even if you don't think it will fit the public estated above!

For instance some papers I like are:

- Estimating the Pricing Kernel using Butterfly Spreads (Koeter, 2016)
  (http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=141700) -> I find the topic of
  distribution functions from option prices interesting, any more
  suggestions?
- Understanding N(d1) and N(d2): Risk-Adjusted
  Probabilities in the Black-Scholes Model (Nielsen 1992)
  (https://financetrainingcourse.com/education/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Understanding.pdf)
- We Don’t Quite Know What We Are Talking About When We Talk About
  Volatility (Goldstein, Tableb, 2007)
  (http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Courses/434/434Context/Volatility/ConfusedVolatility.pdf)

Thanks!